# Lua: Usage rules for the single line multiple variable declaration

Tags: lua, variable-assignment

```
   local x,y=33,44
```

I don't know what this format is referred to as, if anything, I couldn't find any keyword. Assigns local x=33; local y=44. Has the gimmick where the assignment of x does not affect the assignment of y, i.e.

```
x=50
x,y=0,x --x=0,y=50
x=0 --x=0
y=x --y=0
```

Great. The notation relies on the comma to separate where the first variable assignment ends and the second one begins. My confusion lies with cases with inclusion of statements like this:

```
local a,b=
    33 --a=33 b=nil
    for i=1,2 do
    a+=i --a=34,b=nil --a=3,b=34
    a,b=i,a --a=1,b=34 --a=2,b=3
    end
```

The above makes sense, why does the following addition of a comma create an error though:

```
local a,b=
    33 --a=33 b=nil
    for i=1,2 do
    a+=i --a=34,b=nil --a=3,b=34
    a,b=i,a --a=1,b=34 --a=2,b=3
    end,33
```

From my perspective the above should just be assigning

```
a=      33 --a=33 b=nil
        for i=1,2 do
        a+=i --a=34,b=nil --a=3,b=34
        a,b=i,a --a=1,b=34 --a=2,b=3
        end
b=33
```

Seems any addition of a comma after I toss in a condition like a loop disallows me to assign the second variable to anything other than defining it within the first? I don't understand the logic here. Are there rules illustrating why this is. I can't find the information. Lacking keywords here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
local a,b=
    33 --a=33 b=nil
    for i=1,2 do
    a+=i --a=34,b=nil --a=3,b=34
    a,b=i,a --a=1,b=34 --a=2,b=3
    end
```

is equivalent to

```
local a, b = 33, nil
for i=1,2 do
  a+=i
  a,b=i,a
end
```

This is syntactically correct. Hence there is no error message.

```
local a,b=
    33 --a=33 b=nil
    for i=1,2 do
    a+=i --a=34,b=nil --a=3,b=34
    a,b=i,a --a=1,b=34 --a=2,b=3
    end,33
```

Is equivalent to

```
local a,b= 33, nil
for i=1,2 do
  a+=i
  a,b=i,a
end
,33
```

You cannot have `,33` isolated in your code. That doesn't make sense. Hence the error.

As Paul already explained, you can only assign a comma separated list of expressions. A for loop is not an expression, it's a statement. It should be obvious that you cannot have a statement in the middle of a comma separated list of expressions.

Comment: An algorithm that is way more efficient than the one I could create used the above format in itself. I didn't understand and wanted to know what was going on. Now I know and I won't be writing it the way they do. I didn't like alot of the ways they wrote things, but they stressed the fact it was written to be super efficient.....and it runs as such, so I thought maybe there's something to it.  Line 56, I guess they just meant to assign b to nil for some reason...i dont know.  https://github.com/morgan3d/misc/blob/master/p8pathfinder/pathfinder.p8

Comment: why do you post this? I don't see how this is relevant to your question or my answer

Comment: "It should be obvious that you cannot have a statement in the middle of a comma separated list of expressions." That was the main reason I post the above, otherwise I wouldnt have.

Comment: if you're referring to [line 56](https://github.com/morgan3d/misc/blob/f08042105f8c44c8157a4ae33db294321ce1b084/p8pathfinder/pathfinder.p8#L56) they're assigning nil to the second variable then run a for loop. that's not what you're trying to do

Comment: ya....but why would they assign it to nil. if u look at it another way it could have been the above variable assignment the OP was about. if u look at other parts of the code they rly hide where the comma are.

Comment: they do this so `index_of_min` is a local variable, it would be global otherwise. please name a line that is not clear and I'll explain to you. I could not find any hidden commas.
if code isn't clear, rewrite it so it is more obvious what's going on

Answer (score 3):

> The above makes sense, why does the following addition of a comma create an error though

Because as described in the [Assignment](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#3.3.3) section of the Lua manual, it expects `explist` on the right side, which is [defined](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#9) as a comma separated list of expressions: `nil | false | true | Numeral | LiteralString | ‘...’ | functiondef | prefixexp | tableconstructor | exp binop exp | unop exp`. None of that allows the statement (a `for` loop in your case) to be included.

The example where only `33` is on the right side is still valid, as Lua will assign `nil` to all variables on the left side that don't have matches on the right side.

You can assign something arbitrarily complex if you want to, but you need to use an anonymous function and invoke it right away with something like the following:

```
local a, b = 33, (function()
  print("foo")
  return 34
end)()
print(b) -- will print `34`
```